# how to execute "ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES" once in application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-permissions

how to execute ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES? I want to run this code once. How it will be possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file put this line before the `<application>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES" />
```

In your `MainActivity` create an `companion object` like this first:

```
companion object {

        const val REQUEST_PERMISSION = 0
}
```

And then put this line in the `onCreate`method in your `MainActivity` right after the call of the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` method

```
requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES), REQUEST_PERMISSION)
```

Comment: error in arrayof    it suggest that create of

Comment: it is not kotlin. it is java